# How can I create a 3D PieChart with Three.js?

Tags: charts, 3d, three.js

I want to create a 3D PieChart and RidiaChart with Three.js,need your help.

Answer (score 2):

This site allows you to generate 3D graphs using three.js : http://threegraphs.com/

Comment: This links to a service that can create pie charts for embedding into websites via iframe using Three.js under the hood, but as far as I understand it, it does not answering the questions in terms of coding, unless you dig into their source code.